# Alter table SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm just trying to insert two variables into a table to create two new columns.  I can get one variable inserting fine and creating a new column, but struggling to get the right syntax for the second one.  This currently works:

```
mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE importantdetails.extracols ADD  `" . $newCol1 . "` VARCHAR(100)");
```

However I can't get `$newCol2` to insert.  I've tried everything I can think of.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What does `$newCol2` hold? What is the structure of your MySQL statement with `$newCol2`?

Comment: And `$newCol2` is?....

Comment: maybe your mysql user doesnt have ALTER permission

Comment: $newCol2 is a variable which holds text. User does have alter permissions as it works inserting one variable, it's just the syntax i'm struggling to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `$link` no need to add db name `importantdetails` try

```
mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE extracols ADD (".$newCol1." VARCHAR(100),  ".$newCol2." VARCHAR(100))");
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately!  This is exactly what I thought it should be.

Comment: @MatthewWarburton check now updated some of writing miss

Answer (score 2):

To add multiple columns to an existing table, the SQL ALTER TABLE syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD (column_1 column-definition,
    column_2 column-definition,
    ...
    column_n column_definition);

 Ex. ALTER TABLE supplier
    ADD (supplier_name varchar(50),
       city varchar(45));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks yes but this is what i'm struggling with.  I thought this should work:  mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE extracols ADD (".$newCol1." VARCHAR(100)),  ".$newCol2." VARCHAR(100)");

Comment: @MatthewWarburton try mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE extracols ADD (".$newCol1." VARCHAR(100), ".$newCol2." VARCHAR(100))");

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `$newCol2` is not a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) and that you set its type correctly. If it's also a VARCHAR(100), the only problem I can think of is that `$newCol2` is a reserved word.

If you're trying to add multiple columns in one ALTER command, you could do it like this:

```
mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE importantdetails.extracols ADD ('$col1' col1_def, '$col2' col2_def));
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be

```
mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE importantdetails.extracols ADD  ('".$newCol1."' VARCHAR(100),  '".$newCol2."' VARCHAR(100))");
```

Assuming $newCol2 contains the string name of your new column and you want this column to be of type varchar(100)